# Efficient way to pixelate an image by manipulating pixels

Tags: java, image, graphics, pixel

I made two methods for a class called Picture, the name is self explanatory. The getAverageColor() method gets the average color of all the pixels in a certain area of the image specified by the parameters passed in. In the pixelate() method, it uses getAverageColor() to pixelate the image. The whole thing works, however it takes upwards of 2 minutes to pixelate a single image. It takes even longer if the pixelSize parameter is made smaller and the image is larger. So I was wondering if there is a better algorithm for doing this by manipulating the pixels.

```
/**
* NOTE: The smaller the pixelSize the longer the pixelation process takes
*/
public void pixelate(int pixelSize)
{
  Pixel[][] pixels = this.getPixels2D();

  int blockSize = pixelSize;


  Color averageColor = null;
  for(int row = 0; row < pixels.length; row += blockSize)
  { 
      for (int col = 0; col < pixels[row].length; col += blockSize)
      {
          if (!((col + blockSize > pixels[0].length) || (row + blockSize > pixels.length)))
          {
              averageColor = getAverageColor(row, col, row+blockSize, col+blockSize);
          }
          for (int row_2 = row; (row_2 < row + blockSize) && (row_2 < pixels.length); row_2++)
          {
              for (int col_2 = col; (col_2 < col + blockSize) && (col_2 < pixels[0].length); col_2++)
              {
                  pixels[row_2][col_2].setColor(averageColor);
              }
          }
       }
   }
}



public Color getAverageColor(int startRow, int startCol, int endRow, int endCol)
{
  Pixel[][] pixels = this.getPixels2D();

  Color averageColor = null;
  int totalPixels = (endRow - startRow)*(endCol - startCol);

  int totalRed = 0;
  int averageRed = 0;
  int totalGreen = 0;
  int averageGreen = 0;
  int totalBlue = 0;
  int averageBlue = 0;

  for (int row = startRow; row < endRow; row++)
  {
      for (int col = startCol; col < endCol; col++)
      {
          totalRed += pixels[row][col].getRed();
          totalGreen += pixels[row][col].getGreen();
          totalBlue += pixels[row][col].getBlue();
      }
  }

  averageRed = totalRed / totalPixels;
  averageGreen = totalGreen / totalPixels;
  averageBlue = totalBlue / totalPixels;

  averageColor = new Color(averageRed, averageGreen, averageBlue);

  return averageColor;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if there is a more efficient algorithm, but you might see a significant improvement in time if you try and run the averageColor calculations in parallel.

Comment: I can't believe my eyes. Such an operation should take less than 20 milliseconds or so. Avoid calling `getPixels2D` in `getAverageColor` and just pass the array.

Comment: Your nesting of the loops is incorrect in pixelate, and check "> pixels[0].length" vs . "> pixels.length".

Comment: Yves you were right, calling getPixels2D every time instead of just passing it in as a parameter was really slowing it down. It can do this in just a second or two after that fix. Thanks!